# try-catch not working?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, error-handling, try-catch

I'm using a try-catch block in the following Actionscript 3 code:

```
try {
    this._subtitle = new SubtitleController(subtitlePath, _framerate);
    this._subtitle.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, subtitleLoaded);
}
catch (e:Error) {
    trace('subtitle not found');
}
```

The `SubtitleController` constructor then tries to load the `subtitlePath` and throws an `Error #2044: Unhandled ioError`, but the error is not caught by the `try` statement. The error is simply thrown like no `try` statement ever existed.

Sure, I can replace that code with

```
this._subtitle.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function (ev:Event) { trace('subtitle not loaded'); });
this._subtitle = new SubtitleController(subtitlePath, _framerate);
this._subtitle.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, subtitleLoaded);
```

and it almost works, it stops trowing that error, but throws another one instead.

But isn't the whole point of `try-catch` blocks to do that? Why does it not work with the `try-catch`, but it does work with a regular event listener?

Comment: You are probably out of luck, the actionscript libraries that adobe makes are really ugly, multiple types of 'event handler' patterns and exceptions seem very bolted on.. exceptions / error seem to be broadcast often on events vs the original invocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IOErrors/NetworkErrors are asynchronous errors. They are not thrown when the method causing them is called as normal runtime errors. Otherwise the execution would have have to stop completely until a (for example) a file is completely loaded ...

Comment: ah.. makes sense now. so for any other error expect i/o and network errors, it should work, right?

Answer (score 6):

> Basically, since the call is async a
>   try..catch..finally block won’t do you
>   a beans bit of good. It takes a while
>   for the loader to determine the url is
>   bad and then it dispatches the
>   IO_ERROR event.
>   -http://www.mattmaher.net/flexible_code/index.php/2008/01/10/urlloader-stream-error-handling/

Theo is correct; I would merely add to use the `IOErrorEvent` class of the `flash.events` package to handle this for anyone that did not know the method.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("test.mp3"));
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("An IO Error has occured.\n\n", e);
}
```

If your working with a Loader object and not the URLLoader, remember that you need to listen to the contentLoaderInfo property of the Loader object as follows.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
loader.load(new URLRequest("path/to/asset"));

function onIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("An IO Error has occured.\n\n", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found having a class named **log.as** is a bad idea.
Errors thrown from this class do not catch in a try-catch.

I think they were fine before.
I've been using FlexUnit with unit-tests which expect errors.
I have AIR SDK 2.7 installed and recently added AIR SDK 2.01 (for another project) which may have initiated the conflict.

Might be a corner case of the older SDKs or something specific about my build environment.

Renaming the class resolved the problem for me.